# csv-like input text to json string

Tags: apache-spark, scalar

I have an input csv-like file like this:

```
"2017-06-01T01:01:01Z";"{\"name\":\"aaa\",\"properties\":{"\"propA\":\"some value\",\"propB\":\"other value\"}}"
"2017-06-01T01:01:01Z";"{\"name\":\"bbb\",\"properties\":{"\"propB\":\"some value\","\"propC\":\"some value\",\"propD\":\"other value\"}}"
```

I want to get json string like this so that I can create data frame from plain json string:

```
[{
  "createdTime": "...",
  "value":{
    "name":"...",
    "properties": {
      "propA":"...",
      "propB":"..."
    }
  }
},{
  "createdTime": "...",
  "value":{
    "name":"...",
    "properties": {
      "propB":"...",
      "propC":"...",
      "propD":"..."
    }
  }
}]
```

It's semi-structured data. Some rows might have property A, but the others.

How can I do this in Spark with Scalar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to what I understood from your question is that you want to create `dataframe` from csv-like file you have. If I got it correct, following is what you can do

```
val data = sc.textFile("path to your csv-like file")
val jsonrdd = data.map(line => line.split(";"))
  .map(array => "{\"createdTime\":"+array(0)+",\"value\":"+ array(1).replace(",\"", ",").replace("\\\"", "\"").replace("\"{", "{").replace("{\"\"", "{\"").replace("}\"", "}")+"},")

val df = sqlContext.read.json(jsonrdd)
df.show(false)
```

You should have `dataframe` as

```
+--------------------+----------------------------------------------+
|createdTime         |value                                         |
+--------------------+----------------------------------------------+
|2017-06-01T01:01:01Z|[aaa,[some value,other value,null,null]]      |
|2017-06-01T01:01:01Z|[bbb,[null,some value,some value,other value]]|
+--------------------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Above `dataframe's` `schema` would be

```
root
 |-- createdTime: string (nullable = true)
 |-- value: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- properties: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- propA: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- propB: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- propC: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- propD: string (nullable = true)
```